# (PySpark) Problem when read data from local computer

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When I use pyspark to read data (DAT file - 4 Gb) from my computer everything is fine but when I use pyspark to read data from local computer (other computer in my company connect by LAN) there was an error occurs as below:

'' Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o304.csv.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: null ''

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHtHt.png)

If I use pandas.read_csv to read file from local computer, everything is fine (only problem with pyspark). Please help to support in this case. Thank!

My code to read data in my computer (no problem occur):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

path='V04R-V04R-SQLData.dat' 

df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv(path)
```

My code to read data in local computer (problem occur):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

path='//8LWK8X1/Data/Subfolder1/V04R-V04R-SQLData.dat' 

df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv(path)
```

Note:

8LWK8X1 is a local computer name

Comment: its not clear what you mean by my computer and local computer but from what I can see you are trying to read a file remotely. The scheme part are the two forward slashes. Do you have a valid path with which you can open your file remotly? Spark supports ftp so if that works your path would be `ftp://8LWK8X1/Data/Subfolder1/V04R-V04R-SQLData.dat`. Notice that the scheme is now ftp: and not null.

Comment: I try to read my file with your suggestion but the error still occur. Could you share me more options ? The local computer mean all computer connect together through LAN (local area network)

Answer (score 0):

read with pandas and convert that to a Pyspark Dataframe - Easy solution :)

```
Loading into Pandas DF
gam_charge_item_df = pd.read_scv(path)

Creating a PySpark dataFrame
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, the problem is that this data is very large (1-4 Gb) so if we read by pandas there was some problems related to very long time loading and over ram. This is the reason why I need to use some big data library for this thing...

Comment: But - If you are using local machine i.e. if not well equipped with Good processing power and memory then it hardly makes a difference even if you use Spark.